# Display the resortid, name of the resort ,booking count and the total amount collected in each resort

Tags: sql

This is the query written by me:

```
select resort.resortid,
       resort.resortname,
       (count(booking.bookingid))  as  "TOTALBOOKING", 
       booking.totalcharge as "TOTALAMOUNT" 
from resort 
  join booking on booking.resortid=resort.resortid 
group by resort.resortid,resort.resortname,booking.totalcharge
order by resort.resortid;
```

and output:

```
  RESORTID RESORTNAME             TOTALBOOKING TOTALAMOUNT
---------- ------------------------------ ------------ -----------
      1001 TREE OF LIFE RESORT           1       30000
      1001 TREE OF LIFE RESORT           1       48000
      1002 PALETTE RESORTS               1       30000
      1003 GRAND GRT                     1       32000
      1004 GREEN COCONUT                 1       30000
```

Expected Output:

```
RESORTID RESORTNAME           TOTALBOOKING TOTALAMOUNT
---------- ------------------------------ ------------ -----------
      1001 TREE OF LIFE RESORT           2       78000
      1002 PALETTE RESORTS               1       30000
      1003 GRAND GRT                     1       32000
      1004 GREEN COCONUT                 1       30000
```

How to add the count of totalbookings having same resortid ?

Comment: Hello Spratik45, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us your expected results. You should also add a database tag: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to `sum()` the `totalcharge` per `resortid` and `resortname`: so you need just the two latter columns in the `group by` clause (not `totalcharge`).

```
select  
    r.resortid,
    r.resortname,
    count(*) totalbooking ,
    sum(b.totalcharge) as totalamount 
from resort r
inner join booking b on b.resortid = r.resortid 
group by r.resortid, r.resortname
order by r.resortid;
```

Note that table aliases make the query easier to write and read.

This gives you one row per resort, with the total number of bookings and the sum of `totalcharge`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the windowed version of `count()`.

```
SELECT resort.resortid,
       resort.resortname,
       count(booking.bookingid) AS "TOTALBOOKING",
       booking.totalcharge AS "TOTALAMOUNT",
       count(booking.bookingid) OVER (PARTITION BY resort.resortid) AS "totalbookings having same resortid"
       FROM resort
            INNER JOIN booking
                  ON booking.resortid = resort.resortid
       GROUP BY resort.resortid,
                resort.resortname,
                booking.totalcharge
       ORDER BY resort.resortid;
```